# Mongoose Virtual not working

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a mongoose Schema call username and i am trying to concat the user name in a virtual. When i log the virtual in the get or execute a function in these model it is returning undefined.

I have reference the documentation and there example is nesting the model, and i prefer the current model than nesting it.
I hope any body can help me on this.

```
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const UserSchema = new Schema({ 
firstname: {
type: String,
lowercase: true,
required: true
},
lastname: {
type: String,
lowercase:true,
text: true,trim: true,
required: true},
middlename: {
type: String,
text: true,trim: true,
lowercase: true
 }
  UserSchema.virtual('fullname')
.get(function(){
  return this.firstname + ' ' + this.lastname;
})
.set(function(firstname, lastname) {
  firstname = this.firstname;
  lastname = this.lastname;
});
UserSchema.set('toObject', {virtuals: true});
UserSchema.set('toJSON', {virtuals: true});
  });
  const User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

Answer (score 19):

Try this:

```
const Schema = mongoose.Schema
const UserSchema = new Schema({ 
  firstname: {
    type: String,
    lowercase: true,
    required: true
  },
  lastname: {
    type: String,
    lowercase:true,
    text: true,
    trim: true,
    required: true
  }
})

UserSchema.set('toObject', { virtuals: true })
UserSchema.set('toJSON', { virtuals: true })

UserSchema.virtual('fullname')
  .get(function() {
    return this.firstname + ' ' + this.lastname
  })
  .set(function(newName) {
    var nameParts = newName.split(' ')
    this.firstname = nameParts[0]
    this.lastname = nameParts[1]
  })

const User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema)
```

You should then be able to do this:

```
var somebody = new User({
  firstname: 'Some',
  lastname: 'Body'
})

somebody.save(function(err, doc) {
  console.log(somebody.fullname) // Some Body

  doc.fullname = 'Another Person'

  doc.save(function(err, doc) {
    console.log(doc.fullname) // Another Person
  })
})
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I notice that i can see the fullname in the req.user session but when i explicity call it it write 'undefine undefine'. I am using mongoose as my ORM.

Comment: Did you save your user? I’ve updated my answer to show this.

Comment: "UserSchema.set('toJSON', { virtuals: true })" was what I was missing

Comment: Just putting this out there: Moongose 5.8.11 doesn't support arrow functions with getters (and presumably setters).

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue with virtual, returning 'undefined'.
I solved the issue by not using arrow functions (thanks to @Bradyo's comment).
So Mongoose 5.12.7 doesn't support arrow functions too.

Comment: Explain your answers with examples. It gives more meaningful. [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Solves the issue for me. Was using an arrow function and was wondering why 'this' wasn't resolved. Ugh! Forgot that was even an issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

#### Try This:

```js
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const UserSchema = new Schema(
    {
        firstname: {
            type: String,
            lowercase: true,
            required: true
        },
        lastname: {
            type: String,
            lowercase: true,
            text: true, trim: true,
            required: true
        },
        middlename: {
            type: String,
            text: true, trim: true,
            lowercase: true
        },
    },
    {
        toJSON: { virtuals: true },
        toObject: { virtuals: true },
    }
);
UserSchema.virtual('fullname').get(function(){
    return this.firstname + ' ' + this.lastname;
}).set(function(firstname, lastname) {
    firstname = this.firstname;
    lastname = this.lastname;
});

const User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```